# angular2 - Using localized string in ternary operation

Tags: angular, localization, angular2-template

I am trying to add title attribute to my button conditionally i.e. if an expression evaluates to true I want to add some title to the button else do nothing.
However, I also want the title to be localized so the title I want will come from a resource file (like en.json)

I tried using :

```
[attr.title]="typeOfApplication == 'Native' ? '{{'PROJECT.ONLY_DEFAULT' | translate }}' : null"
```

so that when expression evaluates to truthy, I want the localized string corresponding to 'PROJECT.ONLY_DEFAULT' to be displayed.

However I get an error saying:

> Conditional expression typeOfApplication == 'Native' ? '{{' requires all 3 expressions at column 37 in [typeOfApplication == 'Native' ? '{{'PROJECT.ONLY_DEFAULT' | translate }}' : null]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lose interpolation and use regular brackets instead:

```
[attr.title]="(typeOfApplication == 'Native') ? ('PROJECT.ONLY_DEFAULT' | translate) : null"
```

Using interpolation along with data binding (`[]`) will always produce errors, you can only use one of these.